# Can I change the namespace of a .proto file between applications?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Basically, I have a `.proto` definition which declares the package as `main`.

```
package main;
```

This file is being used by two programs. I am rewriting one of them. When I generate the c++ files for this definition, the namespace generated is `main`. This causes clash with the `main` function. Right now I just wrap the header and the source of the generated files with this:

```
#define main protocol

//Generated code

#undef main
```

I want to know if it is safe for me to rename the package in the `.proto` file and if I did, would the resulting protocol buffer messages will be compatible.

Something like

```
package xxx;
//Same definitions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this would be 100% compatible in terms of data using the binary protocol - the binary DAT excludes *all* names, only tag numbers are included.

If you're using the JSON protocol, some names matter - in particular the member names.